# SQL Server- Insert results from dynamic query and variable into same row of a temporary table

Tags: sql-server

How do you insert the results of a dynamic SQL server query and a variable into the same row of a temp table.

Here is the format of the temporary table (#temp)

```
create TABLE #temp (YEAR INT, ACC_AMOUNT Money, REJ_AMOUNT Money,  OUT_AMOUNT Money,TOT_AMOUNT   Money)
```

The Stored PROC is executed by

```
exec  sp_executesql @pSQL
```

and will return values that should go into the columns ACC_AMOUNT, REJ_AMOUNT, OUT_AMOUNT.

```
14569849.11           696235.49             1353464.92            16619549.52
```

I want to insert a variable (@pACCU_YEAR) for the Year and the results of the SP and insert the dyanmic query in the same Row.  This is wrong, but this will give you an idea of what I mean.

```
insert into #temp (YEAR)
values (@pACCU_YEAR)

insert into #temp (ACC_AMOUNT , REJ_AMOUNT,  OUT_AMOUNT,TOT_AMOUNT)
exec  sp_executesql @pSQL
```

This will result in

```
YEAR        ACC_AMOUNT            REJ_AMOUNT            OUT_AMOUNT            TOT_AMOUNT
2014        NULL                  NULL                  NULL                  NULL
NULL        14569849.11           696235.49             1353464.92            16619549.52
```

I would like:

```
YEAR        ACC_AMOUNT            REJ_AMOUNT            OUT_AMOUNT            TOT_AMOUNT
2014        14569849.11           696235.49             1353464.92            16619549.52
```

Comment: What's the code inside `@pSQL`?

Comment: I am a little new to SQL, can you please show me an example of how to select a column that is a variable not within the table?

Comment: Just return it from the stored proc then

Comment: add it the next select whenever you use the temp table...

Comment: Ok, Thanks this worked.  I didn't know you could set a variable as part of the select statement.  I will use the code suggested by Daniel E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select @Year [Year]
    ,Acc_Amount
    ,other fields....
FROM #Temp
```

In response to the question asked in your comment.

Use this after the @pSql is run. Leave the column Year out of the declaration.

Alternatively, after it runs just:

```
update #temp
SET [Year]=@Year
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the code inside `@pSQL`? Why don't do the `INSERT` in your dynamic query itself like

```
declare @pSQL varchar(max);

set @pSQL = 'some sql command;
some_other_sql_command;
.......

insert into #temp (ACC_AMOUNT , REJ_AMOUNT,  OUT_AMOUNT,TOT_AMOUNT)
select blah,blah1,blah2,blah3
from blah_table;';


exec  sp_executesql @pSQL;
```

> can you please show me an example of how to select a column that is a
>   variable not within the table?

use same `SELECT` statement like

```
select @var1 as some_name, @var2 as some_other_name
```

`as some_name` is optional. That's to give a meaningful name to the selected field.